# patch_default_args is True but PyFakeFS don't patch pathlib.Path.cwd()

Tags: python, pyfakefs

I use `pathlib.Path.cwd()` as a default argument in a function signature.

```
def foobar(dir_arg=pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'logs'):
    # ...
```

When I unittest this function with `pyfakefs` the argument isn't patched. But the `patch_default_args` is set to `True`.

Here is the MWE.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest as pyfakefs_ut
import pathlib


class Logging(pyfakefs_ut.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('PyFakeFS activated')
        self.setUpPyfakefs(
            allow_root_user=False,
            patch_default_args=True)

    def test_foobar(self):
        foobar()


def foobar(dir_arg=pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'logs'):
    dir_local = pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'logs'

    print(f'dir_arg: {dir_arg}')
    print(f'dir_local: {dir_local}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Without PyFakeFS')
    foobar()
```

Run this as a test (with activated `pyfakefs`):

```
python3 -m unittest x.py
PyFakeFS activated
dir_arg: /home/user/tab-cloud/_transfer/logs
dir_local: /logs
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.744s

OK
```

Run this usual *without* `pyfakefs`

```
./x.py
Without PyFakeFS
dir_arg: /home/user/tab-cloud/_transfer/logs
dir_local: /home/user/tab-cloud/_transfer/logs
```

The *expected output* when run as a test would be

```
PyFakeFS activated
dir_arg: /logs
dir_local: /logs
```

There is also an [open Issue](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs/issues/704) about that problem. But now I think this isn't a bug but more a problem in front of the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the [feedback](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs/issues/704#issuecomment-1214197228) of PyFakeFS's maintainer.

The question fits to an edge case that is not accounted by the `patch_default_args` argument. It patches filesystem *functions* but not *classes* (as in my case).

A solution is to use the [`modules_to_reload`](https://jmcgeheeiv.github.io/pyfakefs/release/usage.html?highlight=modules_to_reload#modules-to-reload) argument.

To demonstrate the solution with code I separated the MWE from the question into two files.

Here is `x.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib


def foobar(dir_arg=pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'logs'):
    dir_local = pathlib.Path.cwd() / 'logs'

    print(f'dir_arg: {dir_arg}')
    print(f'dir_local: {dir_local}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Without PyFakeFS')
    foobar()
```

This is `test_x.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyfakefs.fake_filesystem_unittest as pyfakefs_ut
import pathlib
import x

class Logging(pyfakefs_ut.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('PyFakeFS activated')
        self.setUpPyfakefs(
            allow_root_user=False,
            modules_to_reload=[x])

    def test_foobar(self):
        x.foobar()
```

#### Reload order

When you use `modules_to_reload` the load order is also important in some edge cases. An example and a solution can be found [here](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs/issues/704#issuecomment-1214295940).

Regarding to the MWE here. When `foobar()` would be located in a sub-module (`sub_x.py`) which is imported implicite in the `x/__init__.py` then the sub-module should be loaded first.

```
modules_to_reload=[x.sub_x, x]
```